# Updating Table with random grade

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, insert-update

I have a function designed to assign grades to specific schools in the table simulated_records, which is based on the number of students and probability of each student getting a specific grade for that school.
I already have all that probability stuff down but am getting errors when trying to update the table with the correct grades. 
I do not know if I am updating incorrectly or am putting the update in an in correct area.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION assigngrades(probs numeric[], school text, record_id bigint) RETURNS void AS $$
 DECLARE
num_grades integer ARRAY[6];
found_school school_probs%ROWTYPE;
num_students simulated_records%ROWTYPE;
random_record simulated_records%ROWTYPE;
num_students_int bigint;



BEGIN
SELECT INTO found_school * FROM school_probs WHERE school_code = record_id;
SELECT INTO num_students * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_students_int FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school;

num_grades[1] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
num_grades[2] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
num_grades[3] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
num_grades[4] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
num_grades[5] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];
num_grades[6] = num_students_int*found_school.probs[1];

FOR i IN 1..num_grades[1] LOOP

    SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
       random_record.grade = 'A';

END IF;
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;
END Loop; 

FOR i IN 1..num_grades[2] LOOP

    SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
        random_record.grade := 'A-';
END IF;
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;
END Loop; 
FOR i IN 1..num_grades[3] LOOP

    SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
        random_record.grade := 'B+';
END IF;
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;
END Loop; 
FOR i IN 1..num_grades[4] LOOP

    SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
        random_record.grade := 'B';
END IF;
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;
END Loop; 
FOR i IN 1..num_grades[5] LOOP

    SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
        random_record.grade := 'C';
END IF;
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;
END Loop; 
FOR i IN 1..num_grades[6] LOOP

    SELECT INTO random_record * FROM simulated_records WHERE school = school_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
    IF random_record.grade = '-' THEN
         random_record.grade = 'D';

END IF;
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;

END Loop; 

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

In all honesty I'm just not sure how to correctly update it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` commands, because

```
UPDATE simulated_records.grade = random_record.grade;
```

updates all rows of the table.